# Como receber vários campos no php e inserir na tabela(mysql), sem saber a quantidade

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Primeira pergunta aqui, então se precisarem de algo a mais me diga por favor.
Eu tenho uma tela simples em html que possui uma tabela básica e nesta tabela tem inputs onde se 
colocam os valores descrição e valor(um sistema de controle de gastos), eu criei no javascript um comando que ao clicar no botão "Adicionar", adiciona mais 2 outros campos iguais aos citados.
Quero receber estes dados pelo php,mas não sei como pois não sei quantos campos a pessoa vai querer preencher e como receber e tratá-los.
Sei que eles virão como arrays e que tenho que transformar para string,mas não consegui executar isso, muito menos colocar na tabela no banco de dados.

Obs: possui o botão salvar que já está configurado,mas não tem os valores que vai inserir no banco.

**Código html**

```
    <table id="tabela">
                <th>Descrição</th>
                <th>Valor</th>

      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="r1[]" id="desc" placeholder="Descrição"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="r2[]" id="valor" placeholder="Valor"></td>
      </tr>
        <a href="#" id="add">adicionar campo</a>
        <input id="enviar" type="submit" value="salvar">

         <script src="main.js"></script>
```

**Código PHP**

```
<?php

require_once "conexao.php";

$desc = $_POST['r1'];
$valor = $_POST['r2'];

$result = count($desc);

for ($i = 0; $i < ($result) ; $i++) {

      $dataString .= " ('$desc[$i]', '$valor[$i]'),";
}

// retira a ultima virgula

$values = substr($dataString, 0, -1);

//a query para inserir os dados no banco 

$sql = ("INSERT INTO tbtable (r1,r2) VALUES $values");


mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);

mysqli_close($conexao);
```

**Código Javascript**

```
const btn = document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', function(){
    var table = document.getElementById('tabela')
    var row = table.insertRow(2)

row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = `<input type="text" name="r1[]" placeholder="Descrição">`
row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = `<input type="text" name="r2[]" placeholder="Valor">`
})
```

Na tabela do banco tem 3 colunas (id,r1,r2), no caso seria resultado 1 e resultado 2.

Comment: o atributo name deve ser r1 ou r2 mas como devem ser mais instancias então você deve inserir []  ficando assim: <input type="text" name="r1[]" placeholder="Descrição">

Comment: Entendi, mas você sabe como recebo este valor no php?

Comment: exemplo: $r1 = $_POST['r1']; porém como ele chegará como um array você terá que iterar sobre esse array $r1 usando um foreach por exemplo.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado pela resposta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Você:** "Sei que eles virão como arrays e que tenho que transformar para string, mas não consegui executar isso, muito menos colocar na tabela no banco de dados."

**O Marcos Vinicius** - o atributo name deve ser r1 ou r2 mas como devem ser mais instancias então você deve inserir [] ficando assim:

```
<input type="text" name="r1[]" id="desc" placeholder="Descrição">
```

**Eu**

> > Uma única declaração INSERT ... VALUES pode adicionar múltiplos registros em uma tabela se você fornecer múltiplas listas de valores. Para fazer isso, forneça uma lista de valores entre parêntesis para cada registro e separe as listas com virgulas.
> >
> > ```
> > INSERT INTO tbtable (r1,r2) VALUES ('pera', '12'), ('uva', '13'), ('maça', '14')
> > ```

```
//recuperando valores passados pelo formulario
$codProduto = $_POST['r1'];
$qtdProduto = $_POST['r2'];

// usando um foreach para construir os values do insert
$result = count($codProduto);

for ($i = 0; $i < ($result) ; $i++) {

      $dataString .= " ('$codProduto[$i]', '$qtdProduto[$i]'),";

}

// retira a ultima virgula
$values=substr($dataString, 0, -1);

//a query para inserir os dados no banco 
$sql = ("INSERT INTO tbtable (r1,r2) VALUES $values");
```

Comment: Funcionou em partes, ele cadastra no banco sim, mas se eu acrescentar mais de um campo com o javascript e colocar os valores, só insere o valor que esta nos campos preenchidos pelo html,ou seja, se eu acrescentar mais 2 campos pelo javascript ele não passa esses valores para o banco de dados.

Comment: @Lucas, no javascript você renomeou os names dos inputs para name="r1[]" e name="r2[]"

Comment: Sim, fiz isso, mas não funcionou dessa forma

Comment: Agora consegui realizar, mas retorna um erro, Notice: Undefined variable: dataString in C:\xampp\htdocs\testetable\index.php on line 12, sabe por que?

Comment: @Lucas, o que estava faltando pra funcionar?

Comment: tem como postar os códigos completos?

Comment: Eu retirei o ponto depois de $dataString.= " ('$codProduto[$i]', '$qtdProduto[$i]'),";,pois não entendi a funcionalidade dele, e por estar retornando o erro,mas quando deixei funcionou, mesmo com o erro

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta com o código como está agora

Comment: seu formulário não tem <form method="POST" action="pagina_destino">

Comment: Inicialize a variável no inicio do PHP $dataString = "";

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado mesmo.